# Form binding <select multiple> to List in Play framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I have a ticketing form that simplified contains a "subject" text field, a "content" textarea and a "to" multiple select.

I expected a multiple select to be able to bind to `list(uuid)` in Play's form mapping, but that is not the case.

`request.body.asFormUrlEncoded("to")` returns a Vector of several elements but `.to` in my mapping is empty. Looking at the source code it seems that Play requires me to put the "to" elements in `to[0]`, `to[1]` etc. But for a multiple select that would be very inconvenient. Is there a better way?

```
case class CreateTicketFormModel(subject: String, content: String, to: List[UUID])

def CreateTicketForm = Form(mapping(
  "subject" -> nonEmptyText,
  "content" -> nonEmptyText,
  "to" -> list(uuid)
)(CreateTicketFormModel.apply)(CreateTicketFormModel.unapply))
```